# Cant Copy Text To Clipboard

Tags: javascript, node.js, hbs

I am using hadlerbars as the view engine for express and i want the text in the variable code to be copied to the clipboard  i tried many solutions . This is my current code

```
function copyLink() {
    var copytext = document.getElementById('alcslink').innerHTML
    let code = copytext.split(":- ").pop() /*formatted */
    code.select();
      code.setSelectionRange(0, 99999); /* For mobile devices */
    
       /* Copy the text inside the text field */
      navigator.clipboard.writeText(code.value);
    
}
```

when i run this it gives me this error in the web console

```
 TypeError: code.select is not a function
```

Comment: Do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: You need to request permission first.

Comment: Oh sorry i forgot to add it i have edited the post now

Comment: A string does not have a select method.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-do-i-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I use it:

Note, it does not work in the snippet engine. You will need to add it to your code.
Sorry.

```js
const writeToClipboard = async (txt) => {
  const result = await navigator.permissions.query({ name: "clipboard-write" });
  if (result.state == "granted" || result.state == "prompt") {
    await navigator.clipboard.writeText(txt);
    console.log('Copied to clipboard');
  }
};

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', async () => {
 const el = document.querySelector('div');
 await writeToClipboard(el.innerHTML);
});
```

```html
<div>copy me</div>
<button>Click</button>
```